# Dynamic views adding in viewpager and go to another fragment when back to the same fragment added views are null

Tags: android, android-viewpager, blogger-dynamic-views

For example : i created one fragmetn in that added 5 views one by one dynamically and replace another fragment then backpress and open same fragment which have 5 dynamic views but when i will will remove any perticular view from view pager then app will crash and throw  exception : java.lang.IllegalStateException: The application's PagerAdapter changed the adapter's contents without calling PagerAdapter#notifyDataSetChanged! Expected adapter item count: 2, found: 1 Pager id: Pager Pager class: class android.support.v4.view.ViewPager Problematic adapter: class

My ViewPagerAdapter :

```
public class DynamicPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

// This holds all the currently displayable views, in order from left to right.
private ArrayList<View> views = new ArrayList<View>();
private List<LatLng> dropList = new ArrayList<>();
private EditableListener editableListener;

public DynamicPagerAdapter(EditableListener editableListener) {
    this.editableListener = editableListener;
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Used by ViewPager.  "Object" represents the page; tell the ViewPager where the
// page should be displayed, from left-to-right.  If the page no longer exists,
// return POSITION_NONE.
@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    int index = views.indexOf(object);
    if (index == -1)
        return POSITION_NONE;
    else
        return index;
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Used by ViewPager.  Called when ViewPager needs a page to display; it is our job
// to add the page to the container, which is normally the ViewPager itself.  Since
// all our pages are persistent, we simply retrieve it from our "views" ArrayList.
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    View v = views.get(position);
    container.addView(v);
    return v;
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Used by ViewPager.  Called when ViewPager no longer needs a page to display; it
// is our job to remove the page from the container, which is normally the
// ViewPager itself.  Since all our pages are persistent, we do nothing to the
// contents of our "views" ArrayList.
@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    container.removeView(views.get(position));
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Used by ViewPager; can be used by app as well.
// Returns the total number of pages that the ViewPage can display.  This must
// never be 0.
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return views.size();
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Used by ViewPager.
@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == object;
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Add "view" to right end of "views".
// Returns the position of the new view.
// The app should call this to add pages; not used by ViewPager.
public int addView(View v) {
    return addView(v, views.size());
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Add "view" at "position" to "views".
// Returns position of new view.
// The app should call this to add pages; not used by ViewPager.
public int addView(View v, int position) {
    views.add(position, v);
    return position;
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Removes "view" from "views".
// Retuns position of removed view.
// The app should call this to remove pages; not used by ViewPager.
public int removeView(ViewPager pager, View v) {
    return removeView(pager, views.indexOf(v));
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Removes the "view" at "position" from "views".
// Retuns position of removed view.
// The app should call this to remove pages; not used by ViewPager.
public int removeView(ViewPager pager, int position) {
    // ViewPager doesn't have a delete method; the closest is to set the adapter
    // again.  When doing so, it deletes all its views.  Then we can delete the view
    // from from the adapter and finally set the adapter to the pager again.  Note
    // that we set the adapter to null before removing the view from "views" - that's
    // because while ViewPager deletes all its views, it will call destroyItem which
    // will in turn cause a null pointer ref.
    pager.setAdapter(null);
    views.remove(position);
    pager.setAdapter(this);
    pager.setCurrentItem(position, true);

    return position;
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Returns the "view" at "position".
// The app should call this to retrieve a view; not used by ViewPager.
public View getView(int position) {
    return views.get(position);
}

// Other relevant methods:

// finishUpdate - called by the ViewPager - we don't care about what pages the
// pager is displaying so we don't use this method.


public boolean isContaint(int position) {
    try {
        views.get(position);
        return true;
    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        return false;
    }
}

public void addLocation(LatLng latLng, AppCompatEditText activeEditText) {
    if (activeEditText == null)
        return;
    if (activeEditText.getTag() != null) {
        LatLng lng = (LatLng) activeEditText.getTag();
        int i = dropList.indexOf(lng);
        if (i > -1) {
            dropList.set(i, latLng);
        } else
            dropList.add(latLng);
    } else
        dropList.add(latLng);

    activeEditText.setTag(latLng);
}


public void removeLocation(AppCompatEditText activeEditText) {
    if (activeEditText.getTag() != null) {
        LatLng lng = (LatLng) activeEditText.getTag();
        int i = dropList.indexOf(lng);
        if (i > -1) {
            dropList.remove(i);
        }

        editableListener.notifyMap();
    }
}

public List<LatLng> getDropList() {
    return dropList;
}

public void doneWithThis(ViewPager viewPager, AppCompatEditText editText,Fragment fragment) {
    if (editText != null) {

        int currentItem = viewPager.getCurrentItem();
        if (currentItem == views.size() - 1)
            createNewView(viewPager,fragment);

        editText.setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.remove_loc, 0);
        editableListener.hideKeyBoard();
        editText.clearFocus();
    }
}

public void createNewView(final ViewPager viewPager, final Fragment fragment) {

    final View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewPager.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.address_editext_layout, null);
    final int pageIndex = addView(v);
    v.setTag(pageIndex);

    final AppCompatEditText editText = (AppCompatEditText) v.findViewById(R.id.editTextTo);

    final View toLine = v.findViewById(R.id.fromLine);


    editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {

        boolean isFocused;

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {

            View currentView = getView(viewPager.getCurrentItem());
            editableListener.isInEditMode(editText, b);

            if (currentView == v) {

                if (b) {

                    Intent ii = new Intent(fragment.getActivity(), LocationSearchActivityNew.class);
                    fragment.getActivity().startActivityForResult(ii, Constant.DROPOFF_REQUEST);
                   /* AnimationUtil.scale(editText, true, new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {


                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                            isFocused = true;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                        }
                    });
                    AnimationUtil.visible(toLine);*/
                } else {
                    /*AnimationUtil.scale(editText, false, new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                            isFocused = false;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                        }
                    });
                    AnimationUtil.inVisible(toLine);*/
                }
            } else {
                if (b) {
                    //editText.clearFocus();
                    int i = views.indexOf(v);
                    if (i != -1)
                        viewPager.setCurrentItem(i, true);

                    if (!isFocused) {
                       /* AnimationUtil.scale(editText, true, new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                                isFocused = true;
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                            }
                        });
                        AnimationUtil.visible(toLine);*/
                    }

                } else {

                    if (isFocused) {
                       /* AnimationUtil.scale(editText, false, new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                                isFocused = false;
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                            }
                        });
                        AnimationUtil.inVisible(toLine);*/
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });

    editText.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
            final int DRAWABLE_RIGHT = 2;
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

                int actionX = (int) event.getX();
                int actionY = (int) event.getY();
                Rect bounds;

                Drawable drawableRight = editText.getCompoundDrawables()[DRAWABLE_RIGHT];

                if (event.getRawX() >= (editText.getRight() - drawableRight.getBounds().width()) && event.getRawX() <= (editText.getWidth() + drawableRight.getBounds().width() + 50)) {

                    if (editText.getTag() != null) {
                        removeLocation(editText);
                        removeView(viewPager, v);
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                    return true;
                }

            }

            return false;
        }

    });

    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            editableListener.performSearch(editText.getText());
        }
    });

    notifyDataSetChanged();

}


public interface EditableListener {
    void isInEditMode(AppCompatEditText editText, boolean b);

    void performSearch(CharSequence charSequence);

    void hideKeyBoard();

    void notifyMap();


 }
```

}

Added dynamic views from my fragment :

```
      if(dynamicPagerAdapter==null) {
          dynamicPagerAdapter = new DynamicPagerAdapter(this);
          pager.setAdapter(dynamicPagerAdapter);
          dynamicPagerAdapter.createNewView(pager, HomeFragmentNew.this);
          pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);

      }else{

          pager.setAdapter(dynamicPagerAdapter);
          dynamicPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

      }
```

}

logcat:
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: The application's PagerAdapter changed   the adapter's contents without calling PagerAdapter#notifyDataSetChanged! Expected adapter item count: 2, found: 1 Pager id: packagename:id/addressPager Pager class: class android.support.v4.view.ViewPager Problematic adapter: class DynamicPagerAdapter
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1134)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1083)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$3.run(ViewPager.java:272)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:549)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)

Comment: can u paste the logcat

Comment: logcat pasted here..